# Incredibly reluctant swapping

Tags: ram, swap

A weird problem has appeared on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. I have 8 GiB RAM and 10 GiB swap area. It worked fine, programs were swapping fast from the SSD, the swapped memory were mostly memory leaks and forgotten mmap anyway... but then something broke it. I have no idea what, I have not noticed it immediately. But now, it swaps incredibly rarely.

The swap space is almost unoccupied, I can have 95% RAM usage and swap space is only 5% full. If RAM fills up, it rarely swaps anything out, it freezes instead, sometimes it recovers after killing a program, but way too often, I have to do a hard reset.

I have checked the swappiness property, but it is set to 60 and setting it to 100 changes nothing. I upgraded Ubuntu to version 17.04, but it didn't help.

If I run a process that takes a lot of memory and uses it actively, it appears to swap out the memory of this process (that just allocated it!), making the process freeze again soon to get back the memory shortly aferwards, in a never ending loop. Almost none of the swapped out memory remains swapped out for long, although I am pretty sure there is enough leaked memory and unused programs to swap.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you check that your swap is running?  `swapon` will indicate if it is operational

Comment: It is running, it occasionally swaps something. Writing `swapon` lists one partition with the parametres of my swap partition, with `PRIO` set to -1. Does it mean it has low priority or something?

Comment: The PRIO is an indicator of the relative priority of multiple swap spaces, and has not real function if you have only a single swap space.

Comment: There is a related post to this which suggested that perhaps the swap format is faulty - the suggested cure is at [https://askubuntu.com/a/847712/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/847712/283721)

Comment: Also mentioned in [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) in the section "Why is my swap not being used"

Comment: You might also `sysctl -a | grep swap` to ensure that the swappiness  is actually set to where you believe it to be.

Comment: Swapiness is 60. I tried to remake the format partition and it seems to work. I tried to do stuff that fill memory A LOT, it froze a few times but recovered and successfully swapped out 1.8 GiB memory (which did not happen before). It seems to be working, but I will accept the answer after watching how it behaves for some time.

Comment: I'd love to be able to claim a bounty (my first!) but...  it's really not my answer:  I feel that if I poke about on AskUbuntu and point to someone else's answer, that they deserve the credit.

Comment: I spent lots of time trying to google that and I never managed. You deserve some credit for pointing that out to me. Please reply so that I can award you the bounty.

Comment: @CharlesGreen: Finding the relevant bits of info leading to a solution can be more difficult than to come up and write up a solution with full knowledge of all relevant info. I think it's perfectly appropriate for you to write a short answer that summarises the issue and the solution and includes a link to the source to claim the bounty. You earned it! :-) We can always close the question as a duplicate once you have your bounty. Without the bounty I'd agree, that there is little benefit in a redundant answer and would opt for an immediate closure as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was entirely different. There was a leak of shared memory by a program that was always running. Shared memory cannot be swapped, so this leaking memory was always in RAM.

The memory belonged to some program required for the graphical environment to run (probably the intel video card driver), so it was always running and cleared only on restart. This caused an accumulation of leaked shared memory attached to a program that was never restarted that could not be swapped, leaving only little memory for other programs that could swap.

This problem could not be properly fixed in any good way because it was a bug in some crucial software package. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 as soon as it came out and the problem doesn't appear there, so it was probably fixed already.

Answer (score 3):

Having checked `sysctl -a | grep swappiness` to ensure that swappiness is set as desired, and `swapon` to ensure that the swap partition is mounted, there remains a possibility that the swap partition has been improperly formatted for some reason.

This can be corrected by

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo /sbin/mkswap /dev/hda8
sudo swapon -a
```

where `/dev/hda8` should be replaced with the partition or swapfile that is suspected of being bad.

The sources for this answer include https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq in the section "Why is my swap not being used?", and [Swap not being used](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847709/swap-not-being-used/847712#847712)