# Ubuntu 18.04 - Swap space not used, Gnome freezing

Tags: 18.04, freeze, ram, swap

I have an issue with my swap space. It is always empty even when it should be used.

In the screenshot below, you can that my RAM is half full, and the remaining RAM is full with cache and buffer.

Each time my RAM gets 100% full with everything, I have a 1-2 seconds freeze. I guess this is the system pausing while freeing some cache to make room.

However, this should not happen. In theory, the swap should start to be used for cache and buffer before the whole RAM gets full, and therefore there should not be freezes since system RAM would always have some free space, cache and buffer would be copied from RAM to swap in the background preventing the freezes.

I checked, my swap partition UUID is consistent in fstab with the result of blkid command and my swappiness is 60.

Is it possible that my swap space is slightly too small to be used ?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/984405) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/973905), can you please try the advice there and see if it helps? TL;DR, try increasing 'swappiness' and reformatting your swap partition because these are the simplest explanations.

Comment: It indeed looks like a duplicate except that I tried everything - changing swappiness from 10 to 90, formatting swap partition, nothing works. Never one single byte is written to my swap partition whatever the RAM occupation rate is.

Comment: You're running a bunch of VirtualBox VMs, which are busy doing whatever they are doing. They are spending an extraordinary amount of time in kernel code, though, which is much more likely to be the reason you are getting freezes. `ps -x -o pid,wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN -o comm` might give you some better idea of where they are waiting. Or consider getting rid of that garbage and using KVM e.g. with virt-manager.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I only have 2 Windows (7 + 10) VMs running, and the freezes occur even when they are near-idle. Do you think I could have more efficiency with virt-manager? Where can I find good documentation about that?
About the command you gave me, all VBox processes seem to be waiting for nothing.

Comment: OK, I see, you have threads display turned on in htop. So two VirtualBox processes with several (CPU) threads each. And `ps` doesn't show individual threads output by default anyway. Try `ps m -o pid,wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN -o comm <pid>` for each main VirtualBox PID.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do you think switching to KVM using virt-manager could show a high benefit for me? I'm doing quite intensive CI (both my VMs are performing 8 MSVC quite intensive compilations in the same time at most, using 6 threads of my CPU)

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for your advice I switched to KVM through Virt-Manager, the difference is huge (+20-30% CPU and RAM performance, + 150% disk reading/writing performance). No freeze any more!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually coming from my VirtualBox Windows VMs making too many I/Os causing gnome to wait its turn to come. I switched to KVM through virt-manager, using virtio drivers, and everything is a lot faster, no freeze anymore.

I checked the difference of performances using Passmark, they are huge:

[image]